# Gnuradio Companion 3.8.2 from MacPorts not launching quartz in Catalina

Tags: macports, gnuradio-companion

I just upgraded to MacOS Catalina, upgraded Xcode, did the xcode-select --install, deleted ports, installed ports, installed quartz, using ports installed gnu radio, LimeSDRsuite and gr-limesdr.  gnuradio-config-info -v tells me that I have 3.8.2 installed.
Running gnuradio-companion just hangs and I have to kill the terminal window to exit (use red window X as ctl-c does not kill the process in the terminal).  When just starting grc in the terminal according to top I do not see quartz start.  If I start quartz first, it just hangs as before.  The mini-apps in quartz seem to work.  If I use the command-spacebar shortcut and type "gnar", I see a "GNURadio - Macports" and the details are show 3.8.2 with the expected date - selecting this brings up a bouncy gnu logo in the tray, but no screen visible.  Right clicking show all windows shows an empty desktop with a "no windows available" message.  I have to right click "force quit" to terminate this.  Going to /Applications/MacPorts/GnuRadio in finder results in the same results.

I am assuming that Quartz is not launching, but not sure if that is quartz's fault or if grc never gets that far.  I would appreciate any pointers on where to start on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the fix was a cliché, reboot the MacBook.  When I relaunched gnu radio popped up a security access approval for python 3.7.  Once I clicked OK, up popped Gnu Radio 3.8.2.